# vpn one-liner login script

Tags: vpn, openvpn, alias

I need to connect to VPN and it's quite tedious. I've tried to do one alias but for unknown reasons it failed. 
Currently `I use openvpn --config client.ovpn` 
Then it prompts me to type in the user-name and password and the token form G auth. But I want to do it in-one line and have alias for that. like  `alias vpn="openvpn --config client.ovpn -uname: r.balejik pass: fkjgndfk1fgf"` is it possible to have kinda one liner? and also this alias doesn't work for some strange reasons when I sourced .bashrc . Or some bash script is a better option?

Thanks,

Rob.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an alias to `.bash_profile`.  You should specify a path to your client.vpn otherwise you might need to be in that folder when you execute `vpn`.

```
alias vpn="openvpn --config /home/user/openvpn/client.ovpn"
```

You then can create a file that contains your username and password and reference it from your client.ovpn.

First thing, create a file called credentials.txt in the same folder as your client.ovpn.

```
nano credentials.txt
```

Inside that file, store your username and password.

```
username
password
```

Save the file, then open client.ovpn and add the following directive.

```
auth-user-pass credentials.txt
```

Once again, credentials.txt needs to be in the same folder as client.opvn as it's going to look there for that file.

Comment: ok thanks it somehow working but `Options error: --auth-user-pass fails with 'creds.txt': No such file or directory` and creds.txt are in the same directory as my client.ovpn file- it's in /etc/openvpn.  And it's also in alias that way: `alias vpn="openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn"`

Comment: ok so I've to be in the /etc/openvpn directory (I'll move it to / (I run it as root )) but I've 2 factor for vpn so it's failing cause it doesn't wait for that 2 factor token