# how to write my own program to login to vpn service

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to automate the following terminal commands into a single clickable or executable or something that involves less entries on my behalf. I use the following to login to my vpn service from terminal. what can i do with bash or script or something else to make a single file that carries out all of the entries below in one shot a template would be amazing if anyone could please help me with this i am new to linux and still getting my head around most things linux but am never going back to windows

```
cd Documents/vpn
sudo openvpn --config ipvanish-AU-Sydney-syd-a01.ovpn 
password for user
Enter Auth Username- blabla@hotmail.com
Enter Auth Password: 123456789
```

Comment: Sorry but why? You can save username and password in a file so you do not need the commands for the last 2. Plus the 2nd one you can make obsolete too with permissions to the command.

Comment: Here is an example: http://askubuntu.com/a/781348/15811